# How to use Promise.all() in for loop?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, axios, promise

I have an axios function, which I want to call several times, then I want to firstly sort received data and then store it. But now all my promises results are undefined.

```
const arr = {...checkbox};
const keys = Object.keys(arr).filter((k)=>{
   return arr[k] == true;
});

let promises = [];
for (let i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
   promises.push(
     axios.get(`my/api/${keys[i]}`).then(
       function(response){
             response.data.sort()
       }
     ).catch((err) => error.value = err)
   )
}
Promise.all(promises).then(() => console.log(promises));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not returning the data from your `then` clause. Try this:

```
for (let i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
   promises.push(
     axios.get(`my/api/${keys[i]}`).then(
       function(response){
             return response.data.sort()
       }
     ).catch((err) => error.value = err)
   )
}
```

and then show it like this

```
Promise.all(promises).then((res) => console.log(res));
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is that you are not returning the sorted data from the Axios promise. You are sorting the data within the promise but not returning it.

```js
const arr = {...checkbox};
const keys = Object.keys(arr).filter((k)=>{
   return arr[k] == true;
});

let promises = [];
for (let i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
   promises.push(
     axios.get(`my/api/${keys[i]}`).then(
       function(response){
         return response.data.sort()
       }
     ).catch((err) => error.value = err)
   )
}
Promise.all(promises).then((sortedDataArray) => {
  const sortedData = [].concat(...sortedDataArray);
  sortedData.sort(); 
  console.log(sortedData); 
}).catch((err) => error.value = err);
```

In this code above the `axios` promise returns the sorted data using the return statement, and the `Promise.all()` method waits for all promises to resolve and returns an array of sorted data